# Too much data to process

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wrote a pretty simple program that creates a random string, asks the user to enter a string and counts how many letter he missed/hit. It goes on until he guesses the random string.

For some reason, when I try to run it I get the error: *"to much data to process"*. I have never seen this error before and don't really know what went wrong and why.

I would love to get your input about this. Here is the code I wrote:

```
import random
import string
def cows_and_bulls(real_string, guess_string):
    hits = 0
    missed = 0
    hits_set = []
    missed_set = []
    for index, letter in enumerate(guess_string):
        if real_string[index] == letter:
            hits +=1
            hits_set.append(letter)
        elif letter in real_string and letter not in hits_set:
            missed +=1
            missed_set.append(letter)
    print(hits, missed)
    return ("hits:" +str( hits), "missed:" +str( missed))

def main():
        random_string = ''.join([random.choice(string.ascii_letters) for n in
                                 range(5)])
        guess_string = input("please enter a guess string")
        if len(guess_string) != 5 or guess_string.isalpha == False:
            print("please enter a new guess")
            guess_string = input("please enter a guess string")

        win = False
        while win is not True:
            hits,missed =  cows_and_bulls(random_string, guess_string)
            if hits == len(random_string):
                print("you win!")
                win = True
                break

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

print(cows_and_bulls("abcd", "abdz"))
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging?

Comment: i tried but couldnt because the program exits right away..

Comment: what's the string you input?

Comment: Works fine for me in Python3.6. Please provide your stack trace.

Comment: You can go with either `win = True` or `break`. You don't need both.

Comment: Do you run it in some development environment (PyCharm, PyDev,...) or from command line?

Comment: @Psytho yes i know, i added it because i thought this might solve the problem

Comment: @MichaelButscher i am using PyCharm

Comment: If you enter a wrong guess (e.g. a single character) twot times consecutively, the program goes in an infinite loop with output of lines with `0 0`. Maybe PyCharm can't handle the mass of output and shows the error. I have never seen such an error in Python itself

Answer (score 1):

You need to fix your main function.

As it stands it will not give you the behavior you want. Running the function like it is now will result in an endless loop of printing hits and misses if the len of the guess is 5 for the same guess (the behavior I got in a jupyter notebook). Depending on the exact enviroment you use to run this can cause trouble.

having your main like this:

```
def main():
        random_string = ''.join([random.choice(string.ascii_letters) for n in
                                 range(5)])
        win = False
        while win is not True:

            guess_string = input("please enter a guess string")
            if len(guess_string) != 5 or guess_string.isalpha == False:
                print("please enter a new guess")
                guess_string = input("please enter a guess string")
            if len(guess_string) == 5:
                hits,missed =  cows_and_bulls(random_string, guess_string)
                if hits == len(random_string):
                    print("you win!")
                    win = True
```

Should fix the problem. If your main function looks like this you ask for input every time the player has not won and the loops stops after winning. Also the player will be prompted to provide new input every time a guess is wrong.

On my end this fixed the being stuck in an endless loop of printing the hits and misses for the same guess.

Answer (score 1):

Also, you need to fix cows_and_bulls method. Change:

```
return ("hits:" +str( hits), "missed:" +str( missed))
```

to

```
return hits, missed
```

Without change, in line

```
if hits == len(random_string):
```

you are comparing string with integer.
Even if you guess the string, you have an infinite loop because `'hits:5' == 5` is False.